# css - div at incorrect position on Firefox

Tags: firefox, css, css-transforms

I'm making a card with css animations, and on Chrome/Safari it works great, but on Firefox one of the divs is getting out of its position. Open [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmorais/p5XCD/) on Chrome/Safari and on Firefox to see what is going on. Does anybody know a fix/workarround to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get Firefox to play nicer by adding

```
.perspective {
    ...
    position: relative;
}
```

That seems to specify the object to which the left side is the absolutely positioned. It must differ by default between Webkit and Firefox.

Unfortunately it looks like there's a timing issue with it now, but at least you're one step closer!

Cool looking effect nonetheless XD!

Comment: NICE! Thanks man! I noticed the timing issue when I was trying to change the left position, but again, it's only on Firefox.